# How do I get rapid SQL inserts with MAX()+1 to always increment between each call?

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js, objection.js

I have an REST-ish endpoint that creates a `day` object and sets its `order` property to whatever the `maximum order is +1`. I'm having an issue where calling that endpoint in rapid succession results in some of the `days` having the same `order`. How do I solve this?

SQL Query is like so.

```
insert into "days" ("order", "program_id") values (
    (select max(days.order)+1
    from "days"
    where "days"."program_id" = '5'), '5')
    returning *
```

And it results in something like

> {"program_id":5,"id":147,"order":38}
>
> {"program_id":5,"id":150,"order":38}
>
> {"program_id":5,"id":148,"order":38}
>
> {"program_id":5,"id":149,"order":38}
>
> {"program_id":5,"id":151,"order":39}
>
> {"program_id":5,"id":152,"order":40}
>
> {"program_id":5,"id":153,"order":41}

If it helps, I'm on Node (Express) and using Knex and Objection to build my queries for a Postgres database. The JavaScript code is as follows.

```
json.order = knex.select(knex.raw('max(days.order)+1'))
                .from('days')
                .where('days.program_id', json.program_id);

return await Days
             .query(trx)
             .returning('*')
             .insert(json);
```

I'm also using `max+1` as I want the order values to increment on a per `program` basis. So `days` of a `program` will have unique `orders`, but it is possible to have `days` of different `programs` with the same `order`.

Thanks!

Comment: That is a really bad idea. For one because it won't scale with growing tables but more importantly it simply won't work correctly with concurrent transactions. Use a a `serial` or `identity` column instead

Comment: Building "significance" into an identity/primary key is not good practice. You can always calculate the number of orders per program, and/or you can include the program id or name on an order if needed.

Comment: Moving away from max makes sense, but that raises another issue. Every `program` has a `start_date`, and that `start_date` is changeable by the user. I'm using the `order` property of a `day` to calculate its `date` from the `program` `start_date`. Knowing the actual `date` of a `day` allows me to query for all `days` that are in the past, all `days` that are today, and all `days` that are in the future.

Comment: I could have a `date` property on each `day` and when the `program` `start_date` changes, I have to recalculate all the subsequent `date` properties of every single `day` associated with the `program`. Hmm. Thoughts @a_horse_with_no_name @Used_By_Already ?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably add `select ... for update` locking to the subquery where you are calculating `max+1`:

```
json.order = knex.select(knex.raw('max(days.order)+1'))
                .forUpdate() // <-------- lock rows 
                .from('days')
                .where('days.program_id', json.program_id);
```

So after that no other concurrent connection can read those rows that are used for calculating max until this transaction ends.

Comment: you can't use `select .. for update` with an aggregate function in Postgres

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name  Thanks, I didn't knew that. I thought it would just lock all the rows that were used to aggregate the result. In that case one has to do one extra select for the same rows without aggregating them or use explicit advisory locks.